# Using MongoExport, how do I control the output of Date fields?

Tags: mongodb, export, date

I am trying to format some data from Mongo into a CSV. One of the fields is stored as an ISODate, so when querying Mongo, comes out like this:

```
... ISODate("2011-11-19T00:23:38.786Z") ...
```

I have a command like the following:

```
C:\Mongo\bin\mongoexport --csv -f "DOB","Name","Email" -c People -d PeopleDataStore -h [hostname]
```

This MongoExport command produces something like the following:

```
{ "$date" : 1321579509347 },"Bob","test@test.com"
```

How can I get the date that is the output of MongoExport to come out like "2011-11-19T00:23:38.786Z", i.e. not an integer representation, and not wrapped in code structures?

Note that I am attempting to do all this from the command line, not from within an application that could process the results. An application will be my fallback plan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't think this is possible using just `mongoexport` on it own, you'll need to write your own little export script or post-process the date values to convert from the integer (milliseconds since 1 January 1970) to the ISO string format.

Comment: Oh well... I guess I'll just write something to do the conversion.

Comment: Holy crap is this weak.  You can't query by date range through the Mongoexport utility unless you do your own conversion to milliseconds?!?

Answer (score 1):

tried on mongo 2.0.1, the output result is exactly what you want

```
c:\Servers\Mongo\bin>mongoexport.exe --csv -f "CreatedTime" -c User -d ce -h localhost
connected to: localhost
CreatedTime
2011-10-28T01:12:40Z
...
```

Comment: thats correct, gives a better result since 2.0.x (I tried a 1.8.3 and a 2.0.3 client)

Answer (score 0):

You can use sed to replace it.

First, you can use the mongoexport to get the file as is.
Once you have the file you can use sed to remove `$date`.

```
sed -i 's/"\$date"/"date"/g' sample.json
```