# MongoExport converts ISO date to numeric values

Tags: mongodb, date

I am using the following mongo export query to export certain records, the problem is that i am getting the date as { "$date" : 1332318976777 }, is there a way we can get the dates in a proper date format:

```
 -bash-3.2$ ./mongoexport -v --cmyCollection --csv -f "d","reportType","reportDatetime" -q '{"reportDatetime":{"$gte":new Date(1332288000000),"$lt":new Date(1332374400000)}}' -o/outputpath
```

Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Vaibhav Goswami.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using MongoExport, how do I control the output of Date fields?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8351889/using-mongoexport-how-do-i-control-the-output-of-date-fields)

Answer (score 0):

Please see this topic on the issue.  It seems like either you will need to post-transform it OR upgrade your client.
[Using MongoExport, how do I control the output of Date fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8351889/using-mongoexport-how-do-i-control-the-output-of-date-fields)